# Defeating Kuvas?

Tags: warframe

I use a Excalibur Umbra, umbra’s Nikana, dread, and Lato. I tried soloing a level 70 extermination with a requiem fissure and I used up all my lives and took me 6 tries to complete. I have not upgraded any of the Umbral mods yet because I have insufficient Endo, I barely last 5 minutes in a Kuva Lich survival, and they basically overpower me and I find it hard to kill even one.

As well as this, 10 minutes ago my friend, who uses Wukong Prime, went with me to complete a hijack mission on Sedna. We were nearly done, then a Kuva Lich showed up, destroyed our Fomorian core, and also killed both of us. Then, we went on another mission, a survival mission with those level 80 Kuva  soldiers and the Kuva Lich. We did that to try get rid of him, but we barely managed past his first health bar before we both died. I can’t remember the lich’s name but it has been like this for every Lich. There has been no time where I have won, even with a full squad, against a Kuva Lich. Can you give tips such as strategies, weapons, methods to kill the troops and the Lich faster, recommended warframes and mods? Thanks.

Comment: Hey man! Welcome to the site. I would recommend making the question title a bit more specific to make it a bit easier for contributors to actually understand your issue. Is it a matter of health and ammo sustain, dps, damage mitigation, overcoming armor, some specific mechanic, etc? Right off the bat, against ferrite armor I would recommend armor reduction like augmented Ash shuriken, or a slash-based solution such as a Hunters Munition build on your gun, assuming I understood your issue.

Comment: You can use Revenant, He returns the damage

Comment: Hope you managed to get him by now :) 

There are a lot of ways you can defeat very strong enemies. I recommend leveling up your favorite warframe/weapon as much as you can - obtain all the best mods, including Riven mods, max them out. Make sure you're using the same damage type on your weapons as is the weakness of the Lich. You can join public games, the random teammates are actually really strong on average. Or just find a strat that makes the fight too easy. Personally, I like using Ivara's invisibility and spam my melee weapon on the Lich.

Answer (score 2):

A simple invulnerability build is to use [Nyx](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Nyx) with the [Assimilate](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Assimilate) augment mod. Mod for efficiency, duration, and strength.

When you encounter the lich you cast [Absorb](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Absorb) (4). This makes you invulnerable for a few minutes while the augment mod allows you to walk at 50% speed.

My lich tank Nyx build (see https://overframe.gg/build/285104/ , Umbral mods are not required):
[image: lich tank]